# How to fix: "Cannot resolve method .setVisible()"?

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, jframe

I am trying to open a JFrame when a certain action happens (they click a button), however, the method `setVisible()` is not working for me. I have used other methods to open it but they are not working as well.

```
extraButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            otherOptions other = new otherOptions();
            other.setVisible(true); // Shows error "cannot resolve method"
        }
    });
```

Trying to open another JFrame

[image]

[otherOption, I am using IntelliJ's preset GUI stuff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KG0NC.png)

Comment: Are you sure `otherOptions` class is inherting properties from `JFrame` class? Like `public class otherOptions extends JFrame` ?

Comment: Does your `otherOptions` class declare `setVisible`?  Does it extend some other class that implements `setVisible`?   (This is a basic Java thing.  An instance method must be declared in the class or in a superclass of the class, or the compiler won't be able to resolve it.)

Comment: I don't think I am, I just added another picture of what I have in `otherOptions`. If I was to extend it or create an instance method where would I do that and how?

Answer (score 0):

Try `otherOption.show();`. There was a time `setVisible` was not yet introduced. I think you have an old compiler or runtime.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to use setOnClickListener method rather than addActionListener.

```
extraButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {

   }
});
```